# Using named instance in connection string

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, dotnetnuke-7

I want to upload my DNN site in customer's host, they use SQL Server 2005 and they use named instance, how can I use named space in connection string ?!

```
<add key="SiteSqlServer" 
     value="Data Source=79.175.164.226,2005; Initial Catalog=jdmedu; User ID=; Password=;" />
```

DNN shows database connection error.

Comment: The connection string is correct, assuming the actual one has the correct userid and password.  The named instance is not relevant since the port number is specified instead.  Post the actual error.  If it is login failed error, the SQL Server error log will contain additional information not returned to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that you can construct ODBC Connections to the DB (outside of your application).

I Suspected that, the problem is in the Configuration of the DB Instance and it can be solved from the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Also, can you check 
http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/connect-via-an-ip-address/

Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

Comment: I can connect to database through SQL server managemenet 2008 r2

Comment: Did you check the connection from the DB server itself? Could you please check the connectivity from the Application server to the DB Server?

Comment: Can you send the exception which occur?